# Flex Mouse Event not working on Alert

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

We have three popups

1. Poppup1 displays list of emails left side and email content is shown on right side.
   A divided box with a data grid showing list of emails and a text area which displays email content
   Resend, Cancel buttons are at the bottom of this popup inside a VBOX
2. When user clicks on Resend button on Popup1, popup2 is displayed with email contents, from and to etc and a  send button at the bottom
3. When user clicks on Send on popup2, an alert asking confirmation with options YES or NO is displayed. Now the issue, mouse event doesn’t work on this Alert but keyboard event works.

Below are the two methods on Popup1 causing the issue. In these, if ExternalInterface.call is commented, mouse event works on the Alert. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
private function onCreationComplete( event:Event ):void
{
     positionHandler(event);
     changeHandler(event);
     this.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, positionHandler);                   
     this.addEventListener(MoveEvent.MOVE, positionHandler);                       
     this.parent.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, positionHandler);                   
     txtMsgDesc.addEventListener(MoveEvent.MOVE, positionHandler);
}

private function positionHandler(event:Event):void 
{
     var position:Point = new Point(txtMsgDesc.x + this.borderMetrics.left + 10, txtMsgDesc.y + this.borderMetrics.top);
     position = this.localToGlobal(position);
     position = Application.application.globalToLocal(position);
     var width:int = txtMsgDesc.width;
     var height:int = txtMsgDesc.height;

     ExternalInterface.call("moveHtml", position.y, position.x, width-5, height-5);   
}
```

And the external interface call calls javascription to set width, height etc. Not able to figure, wats problem with this function.

```
function moveHtml(top, left, width, height)
{
    htmlTextArea.style.top = parseFloat(top);
    htmlTextArea.style.left = parseFloat (left);
    htmlTextArea.style.width = parseFloat (width);
    htmlTextArea.style.height = parseFloat (height); 
}
```

### UPDATE

In the javascript function if i hardcode the values, it works like below
I suspected some issue with parseFloat and tried to check if values are not isNaN but still doesnt work :(

```
function moveHtml(top, left, width, height)
{
    htmlTextArea.style.top = 200;
    htmlTextArea.style.left = 300;
    htmlTextArea.style.width = 100;
    htmlTextArea.style.height = 200; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out that issue. It was html div overlapping flex text area is blocking mouse interaction on alert window.

We have a JSP page which loads the swf file and this JSP contains a div.
And on Flex screen, email content is shown on flex text area for some email types and for other types, the flex text area is hidden and set the content to the div (using div.innerHTML).

And mouse event doesnt work on Alert when alert opens on top of html div. As a workaround, I moved alert to left so that it doesnt come on top of html text area which fixed the issue.